# Parse json and choose items\keys upon condition

Tags: json, rest, parsing, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to parse a json file that I get from a certain REST API.
The json has a few arrays, and I'd like to choose a specific item from an array based on the value of another item.

for example:

```
[
  {
    "item1": true,
    "item2": "value"
  },
  {
    "item1": false,
    "item2": "value"
  }
]
```

I'd like to check if item1 is true, and only then, i want to get the value from item2.

how would I handle it?
I've tried to use a json parser named underscore which is great, but I cant get to the final result.

thanks

Comment: In a loop use __break__ when you get false.

Comment: could you help with an example? maybe in bash?

Comment: Is it okay to show in php?

Comment: (personally I prefer bash, but) any help is greatly appreciated and not taken for granted.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to parse:

```
var objJSON = JSON.parse(yourJsontext);
```

And check for the condition

```
if( objJSON[0].item1 === "true"){

}
```

For shell scripting using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), copy your json to test.json:

```
jq '.[0].item1' test.json
```

You try it on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/#)

enter your json and enter ".[0].item1" as filter

Comment: Why not loop through?

Comment: What if there are hundreds of such element in json

Comment: @benyamin_d .. please upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is from an AJAX, you don't need to parse the response.

```
$.get('api_url', function(response) {
    response.forEach(function (key, value) {
        if (value.item1 == true) {
            console.log(value.item2)
            // Do your thing here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work with the following jq line:

```
jq 'map(select(.item1 == true)) | .[].item2'
```