# Parse json and extract items in array upon condition of nested values

Tags: json, rest, parsing, conditional-statements, jq

I've already asked a similar question here - [Parse json and choose items\keys upon condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31533719/parse-json-and-choose-items-keys-upon-condition), but this time it's slightly different.

This is the Example:

```
[
  {
    "item1": "value123",
    "array0": [
      {
        "item2": "aaa"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item1": "value456",
    "array1": [
      {
        "item2": "bbb"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item1": "value789",
    "array2": [
      {
        "item2": "ccc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'd like to get the value of "item1", only when "item2" has a specific value.

Let's say if item2 equals "bbb", then all I want to get back is "value456".

I've tried to solve it with jq like it worked for me in the issue mentioned above, but to no avail, as I can't extract values from a "higher" level than the one i'm searching in with jq's select and map.

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution is available thanks to the magic powers of the recurse operator, `..`:

`jq -r '.[] | select(.. | .item2? == "bbb").item1'`

Basically what this does is, for each (`.[]`) object in the original array, pick (`select`) only those in which any of the keys recursively (`..`) named `.item2` equals `"bbb"`, and then select the `.item1` property of said object.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution on jq's manual (with #ifthenelse and #Objects) - http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual

```
jq -r '{name1: .[].item1, name2: .[].array[].item2} | /
if .item2 == "bbb" then .name1 elif .item2 != "bbb" then empty else empty end'
```

Comment: But this script doesn't actually work for the JSON object you provided above, does it? It expects the array to be called `array` for every underlying object, instead of having a different name all the time. Under this assumption, you wouldn't need the recurse operator either: you could just `jq -r '.[] | select(.array.item2 == "bbb").item1'`

Comment: that's true. didnt think of the script in global terms, just wanted it to work for my case :). thanks for the addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the magic of .. too powerful for your purposes, the following may be useful.  It restricts the search for the "item2" key.

```
def some(condition): reduce .[] as $x
 (false; if . then . else $x|condition end);

.[]
| to_entries
| select( some( .value | (type == "array") and some(.item2 == "bbb")) )
| from_entries
| .item1
```

If your jq has any/1, then use it instead of some/1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which uses **tostream** and **getpath**

```
foreach (tostream|select(length==2)) as [$p,$v] (.;.;
  if $p[-1] == "item2" and $v == "bbb" then getpath($p[:-3]).item1 else empty end
)
```

EDIT: I now realize a filter of the form `foreach E as $X (.; .; R)` can almost always be rewritten as `E as $X | R` so the above is really just

```
  (tostream | select(length==2)) as [$p,$v]
| if $p[-1] == "item2" and $v == "bbb" then getpath($p[:-3]).item1 else empty end
```